# Why angularJS fails to listen text input when using setInterval() method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body ng-app="" style="background:{{val}};" id="body">
   <input type="text"  ng-model="val" id="color-input">
   <input type="button" onclick="render()" value="Render">
</body>
<script>
          function render(){
               setInterval(function(){myTimer()},5000);
          }
           var i=0;
           function myTimer() {
                if(i<4){
                    colors=["red","green","blue","grey"];
                    document.getElementById("color-input").value=colors[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                         i=0;
          }
</script>
```

I am using a timer of 5sec. But when I press Render Button background color of body remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very 1st thing you need to use angular modularize approach by creating `angular.module` do add components in that like controller, directive, filters, etc. Then provide that module in `ng-app` directive. Also you shouldn't use selectors to get value of the input field, as you have already attached `ng-model` to that field that will make you available that value inside your controller scope.

You shouldn't use  native javascript which will not work in angular context you need to replace `onclick` with `ng-click` & `setInterval` to `$interval` this all will be lie inside angular controller. By using native method from outside angular context will make an problem to update the binding of angular, because they won't run digest cycle. You need to run to digest cycle manually in that case, which is considered as Very bad coding while doing code in Angular.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app" style="background:{{val}};" id="body" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="val" id="color-input">
   <input type="button" ng-click="render()" value="Render">
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  //code here
  $scope.render = function() {
    $interval(function() {
      myTimer()
    }, 5000);
  }

  var i = 0;

  function myTimer() {
    if (i < 4) {
      colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "grey"];
      $scope.val = colors[i];
      i++;
    } else
      i = 0;
  }
});
```